# case when based on group dense_rank() value and row_number() value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, row-number, case-when, dense-rank

here is a task i've been given to get the `qty`(quantity) based on the `outer_index_group` which i get from `dense_rank` **`col1`,`col2`,`col3`** and inner_index_group from `row_number` of **`col1`,`col2`,`col3`**.

Here rules:

**1)** inside each `outer_index_group`, if `col4` has 4055 and 4086, `qty` i should get is in row `inner_index_group` 4086 which commonly in `inner_index_group` 3 or 2.

2- else if `col4` has only 4055, get qty directly from the row.

[image: example data]

the result would be like this
[image]

How do you think i'm gonna do this? I'm thinking about `case when` but i've no idea on how to proceed for this situation.

Thank you very much.

```
    SELECt col1,col2,col3,col4,qty
         ,dense_rank() over (order by col1,col2,col3) as outer_index_group
   , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col1,col2,col3) as      inner_index_group from table
```

Comment: which sql query do you have now?

Comment: `SELECt col1,col2,col3,col4,qty,dense_rank() over (order by col1,col2,col3) as outer_index_group,
 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col1,col2,col3) as inner_index_group from table`

Comment: @ASh any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from
(
    select col1,col2,col3,col4,qty
          ,dense_rank() over (order by col1,col2,col3) as outer_index_group
          ,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col1,col2,col3) as      inner_index_group
          ,RANK() over (partition by col1,col2,col3 order by col1,col2,col3,col4 desc) as rnk
          from myTable
) T
where rnk = 1
```

important part here is Rank() over (..., col4 desc). it will assign the highest rank 1 to rows with max value in each partition of col1,col2,col3. so, if there are rows with col4=4086 in partition, they will get rank 1 and the rest with col4=4055 get rank 2; if such rows are not presented in some partitions, rows with col4=4055 will get rank 1 there.

rank() can be substituted by row_number() if you need only 1 row for each partition (rank() can assign rnk=1 to multiple rows)